# Not smooth image on transparent background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a loading effect on some divs, I put a transparent div on them with a loading image on the center of it.

Here is the CSS:

```
.gear-modal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2147483640;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image:url('https://business.comcast.com/img/preloader.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Please see this jsfiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/margwt9h/3/

As you can see in the demo, the **image** borders are somehow not smooth, why it is showing like this? How this could be fixed?

P.S: The problem is not with the loading image, the same image looks fine everywhere else but not here.

Comment: @PriyaRajaram how this could be fixed then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the image looks really pixelated. Try using different gif image and adjust the width and height. Check out this snippet, where I used different image and set height and width :)

```js
function show_gear_modal(element){
 $(element).css('position', 'relative');
 var custom_modal_html = '<div class="gear-modal"></div>';
 $(element).prepend(custom_modal_html);
 $(element+' .gear-modal').fadeIn();
}

$('.show_loading').on('click', function(){
 show_gear_modal('.my_div');
})
```

```css
.gear-modal {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index:2147483640;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-image:url('http://www.mytreedb.com/uploads/mytreedb/loader/ajax_loader_gray_350.gif');
  background-size: 64px 64px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.my_div{
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div class="my_div">
  Here is some Content....<br /><br /><br />
  <a class="show_loading"><strong>Click here to show the loading</strong></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your image also seems to be pixelated... .

Comment: @behz4d really ? IDK. for me, its looks better than your fiiddle. anyway the point is, Change your loader. search google and get an image with nice resolution !! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it actually is just the image. There are ugly white non-transparent pixels around the edges of the image. Pretty obvious when you put just a plain black background behind it.

If you don't like how it looks I suggest you find a different image.

Comment: Then why all loading images I try looks like this?